# How to start java program with hidden terminal

Tags: java, linux, shell, terminal

How can i create shell script for linux, Which will start my java program and then exit itself

Like:- 
create new process with no terminal-> java "Test".
exit terminal itself.

i have tried with Fork and exec but i couldn't get any of it 
please help me

Comment: How are you executing the script? Just a double-click on it? What OS do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Python script, which is pritty straightforward to use. 
Just add process as background process n it will start terminal hidden

Else 
Put & symbol after your program

Answer (score 0):

have you tried nohup which allows to run command./process or shell script that can continue running in the background after you log out from a shell:

Check here  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html